# Is mingw still active?

Tags: mingw, mingw32, mingw-w64

[Mingw.org](http://mingw.org/) obviously isn't completely dead, but the latest version there is gcc 4.5.2, while 4.6 is already old news.
Does anyone know where I can get mingw-gcc 4.6+? Is [mingw-w64](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/) more active? They seem to have 32bit builds too, so is that just the new mingw?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, this is probably a very personal topic, and here's my very tainted view on things:

I provided a GCC 4.6/4.7/4.8 build for mingw-w64 (see link below). I do so because they provide both a 64-bit and 32-bit capable CRT, which mingw.org (the old one) does not, and is not planning to.

Mingw.org development seems quite halted, although they still provide updates, I'm not clear what these are (quite frankly I don't follow them either). MinGW-w64 has support for DirectX, DDK, and the *_s APIs, among other things, which the old mingw.org still does not have (or at least not as complete).

Note the two compilers are not sworn to binary compatibility, so you'll need everything compiled by one vendor's toolchain (either mingw-w64 or mingw.org).

There are packages available for various Linux distributions, and Windows users can use [the installer](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/installer/mingw-w64-install.exe/download), [MSYS2](http://msys2.github.io/) (which comes with a package manager and a huge amount of prebuilt packages), [TDM-GCC](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/), and [Nuwen's MinGW distro](https://nuwen.net/mingw.html) which includes the Boost libraries.

Comment: MSYS2 comes with package manager that can download toolchain binaries. Looks quite official to me. You can also download package sources ( https://github.com/Alexpux/MINGW-packages ) from MinGW developers and compile more recent toolchain version yourself. Looks official to me too.

Answer (score -1):

I see [`< 14 hours ago` on the Modified time](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Automated%20Builds/) for MinGW-w64, so it looks pretty active to me...
(They're actually 32-bit, btw.)

Comment: So should I be using mingw-w64 instead of mingw32? That is my question.

Comment: w64 means 64-bit compatibility.

Comment: @Ha Is that for the Host machine or the target compiler. MinGW 32 has a i686-w64-mingw32 toolchain in it.